# Perform spherical projection of image in python

Tags: python, pygtk, python-imaging-library, polar-coordinates

I am writing a program using PyGTK that displays a gtk.Image. The desktop is projected onto the inside of a spherical dome. If the image displayed is rectangular on the screen, once projected onto a sphere it gets distorted.

To help picture this: The desktop itself is square. The center pixel of the desktop projects to the zenith and a circle inscribed inside the square desktop becomes the horizon (0 degrees elevation in polar coordinates). Everything outside that (in the corners of the desktop) is not displayed.

I would like to somehow modify the gtk.Image such that it still appears rectangular on the spherical surface. I'm sure there are lots of details in how this projection could be done, but very simplistically I have to convert the rectangular image into a curved trapezoid. Converting to a range of polar coordinates (e.g., map this rectangle to the area between two azimuth and two elevation angles) would be a good first approximation, though you can imagine if the elevation angles are 0 and 90, the resulting image will be a wedge of the sphere and not look rectangular at all.

How can I apply transformations like this to a gtk.Image (or its underlying Pixbuf)? Is there a package already that can do this? If not, how should I go about writing it from scratch? Presumably I would have to pull out the pixel values, map them to some new grid, and replace the original image. I just don't want to reinvent something that has already been done.